# How can i create ToggleButton with image and text?

Tags: silverlight

I want to create ToggleButton that contain image on the center and text on the button.

I try to do it by define new usercontrol - but its not good way.

How can i do it on silverlight ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<ToggleButton>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="..."/>
    <TextBlock Text="Click me"/>
  </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```